# How to assign value to parameter in JSON body using Rest Assured-Java

Tags: java, json, rest, parameters, rest-assured

I have the following JSON body in which the `postingDate` is a parameter. Can anybody help me out with a java code that will replace the parameter postingDate to a value like `15112019`. The below JSON I am fetching through java code in a String variable.(This JSON is given by developers, they use postman for testing)

```
{
    "submissionRequestDTO": {
        "applicationRequestDTO": {
            "selectedProductDTOs": [
                {
                    "allowedProductClass": "LOANS",
                    "applicationRequestType": "NEW",
                    "productGroupCode": "ABADB",
                    "productGroupName": "Home Loan",
                    "productGroupType": "LOAN"
                }
            ]
        },

            "submissionDate": {
                "sqlDate": 1525026600,
                "dateString": "{{postingDate}}",
                "sqltimestamp": 1525026600
            },
            "submissionReceiptMode": "FF",
            "submissionValueDate": {
                "sqlDate": 1525026600,
                "dateString": "{{postingDate}}",
                "sqltimestamp": 1525026600
            },
            "submittedBy": "user",
            "targetUnit": "PP"
        }
    } }
```

The code that I have to send a post request

> ```
> > Response rs = given().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
> >                 .auth().basic("ID", "PWD").
> >                 header("Content-Type", "application/json").
> >                 when().log().all()
> >                 .body(JiraApiPractice.ReadJSONPayloadRequest().toString()). //Reading the payload 
> >                 post("submissionDrafts").
> >                 then().             
> >                 extract().response();
> ```

P.S. I know of String replace but I want to know if there is any method to do this via Rest Assured

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest option would be to call .replace("{{postingDate}}", your_value) when you pull in the body.

```
Response rs = given().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                 .auth().basic("ID", "PWD").
                header("Content-Type", "application/json").
                 when().log().all()
                .body(JiraApiPractice.ReadJSONPayloadRequest().toString().replace("{{postingDate}}", your_value))
                .post("submissionDrafts").
                 then().             
                 extract().response();
```

If you think you'll be adding in more stuff like this, it may be worth looking at a template solution, possibly this:
https://github.com/HubSpot/jinjava

PS, just seen your 'PS', I dont believe Rest Assured has anything native to their library for this.